# Multiple graphs on one picture (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, graph

I have a problem with my python code. I would like to make a multiple graphs on one picture, but with 2 graphs in a top line and only 1 in bottom line, but the bottom one should be wider (width of two top graps). Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib.image import NonUniformImage
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter  


plt.figure(1)

#1
plt.subplot(221)
plt.title('linear')

#2
plt.subplot(222)
plt.title('log')

#3
plt.subplot(224)
plt.title('symlog')


plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08, left=0.10, right=0.95, hspace=0.3,
                    wspace=0.35)
plt.show()
```

If I change the third graph e.g. `plt.subplot(223)` it just moves it from left to right. How can I make it wider and put it in two places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`subplot2grid()`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib.image import NonUniformImage
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter  


plt.figure(1)

#1
plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0))
plt.title('linear')

#2
plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,1))
plt.title('log')

#3
plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1,0), colspan = 2)
plt.title('symlog')


plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08, left=0.10, right=0.95, hspace=0.3,
                    wspace=0.35)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can customize it by using [GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html):

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

gs=GridSpec(2,2)

#1
plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
plt.title('linear')

#2
plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
plt.title('log')

#3
plt.subplot(gs[1,:])
plt.title('symlog')
```